# MySQL Database connectivity with arduino uno through WiFi

Tags: mysql, database, arduino-uno

I'm making a RFID attendance system. I want to connect my hardware system(RFID reader integrated into arduino) to  database(MySQL) through WiFi or Ethernet Shield, but i don't know how to do it.
Can any one help me out by simplifying the steps to follow?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take some time to read [ask].  This question is too broad

Answer (score 0):

You could make a simple php (apache) webServer and send http requests to it through the arduino. Php can then handle the connection to the database. There may be more options though.